# fetching data from excel in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to fetch a column from excel with rows more than 17500. Now problem is that when i call it in MATLAB , it does not gives me whole matrix with all data. it fetches data from somewhere in middle.

Now the real problem is that i have to add up 4 numbers in the column and get average , save it in another column and proceed to next consecutive set of numbers and repeat again till the end..How could i do that in MATLAB .Please help me solve this problem as i am just a rookie. Thank you.

so far i have done is this:

```
clc
g=xlsread('Data.xlsx',1,'E1:E17500');
x=1;
for i = 1:(17500/4) %as steps has to be stepped at 4 since we need avg of 4      
      y{i}=((g{x}+g{x+1}+g{x+2}+g{x+3})/4); 
      x=x+4;
end
xlswrite('Data.xlsx', y, 1, 'F1:F4375');
```

Comment: The `for` loop is incorrect. Instead of iterating `i` from 1 to 17497 at an interval of 4, you are iterating from 1 to 4275 at an interval of 1. Change it to `1:4:17500`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several things here: `xlsread` with one output gives you a numeric matrix of doubles (not a cell-array). Therefore you should address entries with `()` and not with `{}`. The for-loop can be omitted when we use [`reshape`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to create a matrix with dimensions `4x4375`. The we calculate the average of the 4 values in each column directly with [`mean`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) (evaluated over the first dimension). To get a column-vector again we have to transpose the result of `mean` using [`'`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html).

*Here is the code:*

```
g = xlsread('Data.xlsx',1,'E1:E17500');
y = mean(reshape(g,4,[]),1)';
xlswrite('Data.xlsx',y,1,'F1:F4375');
```

---

To see in detail what happens within the code, let's see the results of each step using random data for `g`:

*Code:*

```
rng(4);
g = randi(10,12,1)
a = reshape(g,4,[])
b = mean(a,1)
y = b'
```

*Result:*

```
g =
    10
     6
    10
     8
     7
     3
    10
     1
     3
     5
     8
     2
a =
    10     7     3
     6     3     5
    10    10     8
     8     1     2
b =
    8.5000    5.2500    4.5000
y =
    8.5000
    5.2500
    4.5000
```